# Confused about Laravel's architecture

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a little confused about how exactly I should approach using Laravel. Right now I have a React application that runs through NPM. This then calls restful PHP API's. So more or less my backend and frontend are separate.

In Laravel, it seems that you develop your frontend within Laravel itself (reminding me of applications like WordPress) with it's MVC architecture and routing capabilities.

Should Laravel be used just for API development? Should I be looking to integrate my app (based on create-react-app) into laravel itself? Am I thinking about all this completely incorrectly?

Again forgive what I'm sure is such a newbie question and any resources you could point me to in helping me understand the framework would be great.

Answer (score 2):

An independent UI communicating with an API would be a SPA, Single Page App. And depending on the size or complexity of your application, that's a completely valid way to go. Especially if you can conceive of a non-browser platform like a mobile app communicating with your API at some point down the road.

Laravel Blade Views are entirely optional. They're a really nice templating engine, and not necessarily incompatible with React at the same time either. But if you're more comfortable managing your UI in a separate codebase, the short answer is, it all depends, so do what you're comfortable with.